# SSIS Export to RDB doesn't work with NonUnicode Page File (8859-9)

Tags: ssis, hebrew, codepages, non-unicode, oracle-rdb

I'm trying to export data from a table in MS SQL Server 2008 R2 to a RDB Database.
But I'm having problems to export Hebrew strings to RDB because my SQL Server is Unicode and my RDB is Non-unicode.

Here are the details:

1. I'm using Oracle RDB Data Provider for .NET 
   [image: RDB Connection]
2. I have a Non-Unicode Text field in the target table, and even if I convert the data to 28598 string, the data still get in Unicode format in RDB (and it becomes unreadable).

[image: SSIS Data Conversion]

Here are the results:
[image: RDB Results]

3. I've added a Grid Data Viewer to check if the data is going in the right format and it looks like it is.
   [image: SSIS Grid Viewer]
4. I went even further and configured manually the ADO.NET External Columns property for this specific Column to match the data type (automatically he recognizes it as Unicode, which is not).
   [image: ADO.NET Advanced Edit]

For this I had check FALSE the External Data Validation. Otherwise SSIS would start to run.
[image: ADO.NET Advanced Edit part 2]

**If anyone have experience writing Non-Unicode data in RDB from SSIS please advise me. It can be Hebrew or any other language that uses Non-Unicode characters.**

Comment: You have unicode data in your source database. Your target database does not have a table which unicode data types? I found RDB could be both Oracle Rdb and a Perl based database of the same name-which are you using? What is the table definition in SQL Server? What are you doing in the Data Conversion step?

Comment: My Database is _Oracle RDB_, but i'm not the DBA and he does not allow  unicode types because is a very old db for legacy systems. The conversion that I'm doing is from **Unicode String** (nchar(128)) to **String (DT_STR) 28598 (128)** (you can see in one of the printscreens).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem. I replaced the connection provider from *.Net Providers\ Oracle RDB Data Provider* to **ODBC**.


For this I had to download the *ODCB driver for RDB Databases* from Oracle web site (32 bit version) and configure a System DSN in Windows *ODBC Data Source Administrator*.

[image: SSIS Connection Manager & ODBC Data Source Administrator]

In my opinion there's a bug in the **Oracle RDB Data Provider for .NET** that only allows Unicode data.
If Oracle updates this driver, I wish I could use the .NET provider instead of ODBC.